# GPU based algorithm on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a function which perform some mathematical operations and need a 16gb GPU system, But this function will not be triggered always and rest of time my system will not be in use. I came to know about AWS Lambda.
Can I run GPU based algorithm on Lambda?? So that whenever I need GPU, I will get the system on cloud. I need a little description about it.

Comment: Do we know the situation has changed? 
Is there GPU available for Lambda?

Comment: I don't think so @Aleksei

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't specify the runtime environment for AWS Lambda functions, so no, you can't require the presence of a GPU (in fact the physical machines AWS chooses to put into its Lambda pool will almost certainly *not* have one).

Your best bet would be to run the GPU-requiring function as a Batch job on a compute cluster configured to use p-type instances.  The guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-gpu-ami.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Currently lambda doesn't have GPU.

However, if you just need to do inference; the emulation via CPU works fine on AWS lambda; here is an article that goes into more details:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-deep-learning-models-with-aws-lambda-and-tensorflow/

Answer (score 3):

Batch is a good solution for certain types of workload. 
Another option is [GPUs on ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/orchestrating-gpu-accelerated-workloads-on-amazon-ecs/), which could be used for running frequent tasks utilising GPU.